# Web api Entity-Framework nests parent inside child element

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-fluent-api

I am having an issue when trying to include the Type of an Invoice inside it. Entity framework populates the nested entities in a loop so I end up with the parent nested inside the nested child entity after mapping.

I have configured the relations as follow:

```
public partial class Invoice : IEntity<string>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Type> Type { get; set; }
}

public partial class Type : 
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

As of Fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Type>(entity =>
entity.HasOne(t => t.Invoice)
   .WithMany(f => f.Type)
   .HasForeignKey(f => f.Number)
   .HasPrincipalKey(f => f.Number);
}
```

As a result I'm getting:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Number": "123",
        "Type": {
                  "Number": "123",
                  "TypeEnvoie": "PDF",
                  "Invoice": {
                            "Id": "1",
                            "Number": "123",
                            "Type": { ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not
> supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is
> larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

This is a common error of ef core.

We usually add the following configuration to the `ConfigureServices` method of `startup.cs` to solve this problem(for 3.0 and above)：

```
 services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
   options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
```

Notice that the premise is to download **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson** dll in NuGet First.

Here is the result:

[image]